# SharePoint - Update List Item if ID exists else AddItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list with 100s of items that I have initially populated from a table in SQL. Now, I would like to update those items that have changed and add new items. How can I update the items based on a column in that list? Any help is much appreciated.

This is how I have added the items initially:

```
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List oList_Donors = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("XYZ");

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = "dsn=abc;uid=efg;pwd=hij;DataSource=klm";
                connection.ConnectionTimeout = 100;
                connection.Open();

                OdbcCommand command_abc = new OdbcCommand("Select * From vw_SP_abc_efg", connection);

                try
                {
                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command_abc.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            var obj0 = reader.GetValue(48);
                            var obj1 = reader.GetValue(0);
                            var obj2 = reader.GetValue(33);
                            var obj3 = reader.GetValue(47);
                            var obj4 = reader.GetValue(42);
                            var obj5 = reader.GetValue(42);


                            ListItem oListItem_abc = oList_abc.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);


                            oListItem_abc["Title"] = (obj0 == null || obj0.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(48).ToString();
                            oListItem_abc["abc_x0020_ID"] = (obj1 == null || obj1.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                            oListItem_abc["Excluded_x0020_By"] = (obj2 == null || obj2.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(33).ToString();
                            oListItem_abc["Excluded_x0020_On"] = (obj3 == null || obj3.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetDateTime(47).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            oListItem_abc["Reason"] = (obj4 == null || obj4.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(42).Substring(50, reader.GetString(42).ToString().Length - 50);
                            oListItem_abc["Publish"] = (obj5 == null || obj5.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(42).Substring(50, reader.GetString(42).ToString().Length - 50);


                            oListItem_abc.Update();

                            context.ExecuteQuery();

                        }

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Error is:" + exception);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do you have the sharepoint ID for the item ?

Comment: I would have an ID not the SharePoint Id. I could activate the sharepoint id too

Comment: if you have a primary key that you can map the both just do a caml query to get the item and update it

Answer (score 0):

First i would do a database query as you already have. After that you get the ID of the DB item and all other information (for example timestamps, other fields, ...). With this item within the reader/loop i would create for each db item a caml query which you fire against your sharepoint list an filter by the database id. Then you would get returned a Listitem. I not, then create new item in list from db item.

If you get a Listitem you can compare the fields of the sharepoint items with the db fields of the reader object.

If there are any differences, you can update the listitem.

But be careful, such operations on sharepoint lists with many items, are very expensive (time) and long running.